# Multiple access to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I have a function that add 1 each second to a variable and I want to add a function (called by click) that subtract 3. But I have (logically) problems because the variable is accessed by both functions.

The recursive function that increment each second is this one :

```
function incrementBD() 
{
    var BD = parseInt(document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML);
    BD = BD+1;
    document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD;
    setTimeout('incrementBD()',1000);
}
```

And the function that subtract 3 is this one

```
function less3()
{
    var BD = parseInt(document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML);
    BD = BD-3;
    document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD;
}
```

For now, my variable is stored in a  I could work on it directly in Javascript.

But what should I do about the multiple access problem ?

Thank you for you help ! =)

EDIT : I created (as suggested) a global variable. When I click it subtracts 3 as expected but the variable comes back to 1 at each try.

```
var BD;

function incrementBD() 
{
BD = parseInt(document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML);
BD = BD+1;
document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD;
setTimeout('incrementBD()',1000);
}

function less3()
{
BD = parseInt(document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML);
BD = BD-3;
document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD;
}
```

EDIT 2 Since this code seems to work for other people here is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//FR" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="fonctions.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="incrementBD()">

    <div id="content">
        Broken Dreams : <span id="divBD">0</span>
    </div>

    <a href="" onclick="less3()">Minus 3</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no concurrency problem - JavaScript is single threaded.  Once a function/event handler begins running, it will run to completion before anything else happens.  Storing a variable in a bit of HTML is a bit odd though...

Comment: Storing the value in the div is a bit ugly, but there is nothing actually wrong with the part of the code you've shown. I ran it and it works as it should; it certainly doesn't "come back to 1 at each try".

Comment: @Boann : So it's may be my html code that causes the problem. I add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the variables, but the link:

```
<a href="" onclick="less3()">Minus 3</a>
```

Every time you click it, it does what links do, and navigates to `""`, which reloads the current page.

To prevent this, return `false` from the onclick handler to prevent the default action of the <a> tag:

```
<a href="" onclick="less3();return false;">Minus 3</a>
```

Or, use a button:

```
<button onclick="less3()">Minus 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the scopes comprimising your options. You could use a global variable to achieve this:

```
var BD = 0; //global var
function incrementBD() 
{
    BD = BD+1; //uses global var (not the html value)
    document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD; //"prints" the result to the html
    setTimeout('incrementBD()',1000);
}

function less3()
{
    BD = BD-3; //use the same global value
    document.getElementById('divBD').innerHTML = BD; //"print" it again
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. The function subtracts 3 but the variable comes back to 1 just after at each try.

Comment: @LH Uh what's the point of creating a global variable if you don't use its retained value?